# Is exchangePattern in JMS component only consumer parameter or common (consumer and producer)?

Tags: apache-camel

In jms query parameters [table](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/jms-component.html) `exchangePattern` is indicated as only consumer parameter.
[image]

But after `exchangePattern` is set for a producer too.
[image]

Is this parameter common (producer too) or only can set on the consumer?

Answer (score 0):

It should only apply to the consumer as you don't expect a reply when you are producing a JMS message - that's an InOnly Message Exchange Pattern (MEP).

The MEP in the consumer case for InOut allows the resulting message to propagate back to the location specified in the `JMSReplyTo` JMS header after it has reached the end of the route.